# Flex progress bar setup

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar

I am trying to make a progress bar to show the my application loading status. I google a lot but it only shows how to use progress bar for elements (ex: images, datagrid). I need to know the progress bar setup for the entire application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex already shows a progress bar while the application loads - you can use `barColor` style to change its color.

If you want to use your custom progress bar, define it in an ActionScript class and assign the class to the `preloader` property of the [<mx:Application/> tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#preloader).

> `preloader:Object`
>   Specifies the path of a SWC component class or ActionScript component class that defines a custom progress bar. A SWC component must be in the same directory as the MXML file or in the WEB-INF/flex/user_classes directory of your Flex web application.
>
> Note: This property cannot be set by ActionScript code; it must be set in MXML code.